# phpで変数が宣言されていることだけを判定したい(中身はnullでも良い)

Tags: php

phpで変数が宣言されていることを判定する場合isset()を使いますが、nullでないことも判定に含まれています。
そのとき中身がnullかどうか関係なくtrue判定できる方法はないでしょうか。

例

```
fruits["banana"] = 1;
fruits["orange"] = null;

isset(fruits["banana"]); // true ： 意図通りの結果になっている
isset(fruits["apple"]);  // false： 存在しないので意図通りの結果になっている
isset(fruits["orange"]); // false： 存在するのでtrueが欲しいがisset()だとfalseになってしまう
```

この例だとfruits["orange"]は存在するのでそこだけを判定する方法を探しています。
もちろん存在しない場合の余計なエラーも出ないようなものです。(isset()がそうなっているように)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

公式の isset() のマニュアルに書いてありますね。

https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.isset.php

```php
// キー 'hello' は NULL と等しいのでセットされていないと見なされる。
// もし NULL なキー値に対してチェックを行いたい場合、次を試してみること:
var_dump(array_key_exists('hello', $a)); // TRUE
```

Comment: undefined絡みで検索した場合もarray_key_existsの記事が見つかりました。ありがとうございます。